# Convert binary string into decimal

Tags: c++, arduino

I would like to convert a string that is a binary to a decimal.

Here is what the fullCard value is.

```
fullCard = "1000000100000101111101"
```

Here is what it should look like after being converted to decimal

```
fullCardInt = 2113917
```

Main.ino

```
String fullCard;                     // binary value full card number 

int fullCardInt = bin2dec(const_cast<char*>(fullCard.c_str()));  
// I get -1 which is a failure. 

serial.print(fullCardInt);

int bin2dec(const char *bin)
{
  int result=0;
  for(;*bin;bin++)
  {
    if((*bin!='0')&&(*bin!='1'))
      return -1;
    result=result*2+(*bin-'0');
    if(result<=0) return -1;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The `strtol` function in the standard c library takes a "base" parameter, which in this case would be 2. You could see if you can use that

Comment: Not sure what the question is here.

Comment: I have a string that is a binary value of "1000000100000101111101". I want to convert that string into a decimal value which should look like this 2113917. I used this tool to get the decimal value to make sure my string was indeed a legit binary number http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/ @user4581301

Comment: And the question is? Why doesn't your code work, whats the problem?

Comment: It gives me a -1 returned on my bin2dec function. @tkausl

Comment: What debugging did you try?  Which `-1` and when it happens matters.  For example did you try printing `result` or `*bin` at each iteration of the loop?

Comment: So the function failed. I don't see any mistakes in it, so the usual suggestion applies: Step through it with a debugger and see where the function does something you don't expect.

Comment: @mdatsev this is an arduino/avr, that is massive overkill, can you imagine the tens of percent of flash space lost to add that function for something this trivial? assuming there is even enough flash to hold that function and it side effects at all.

Comment: This is a fair point, I was just stating an option, not posting an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1000000100000101111101` has 22 bits.

`int` on Arduino is 16-bit.

The solution is to use `long` (32-bit) instead of `int`.

Answer (score 3):

since this function is portable did you test it?  did you instrument it to see what was going on?  We are not here for code reviews nor to debug code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bin2dec(const char *bin)
{
  int result=0;
  for(;*bin;bin++)
  {
    if((*bin!='0')&&(*bin!='1'))
      return -1;
    result=result*2+(*bin-'0');
    if(result<=0) return -1;
  }
  return result;
}


int main ( void )
{
    printf("%d\n",bin2dec("1000000100000101111101"));
    return(0);
}
```

I get 2113917 as a result.

your code could use a couple of shortcuts but functionally it is sound.  you didnt show us how you called it.

ahh yes, plus one gre_gor's answer that is the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

short bin2dec(const char *bin)
{
  short result=0;
  for(;*bin;bin++)
  {
    if((*bin!='0')&&(*bin!='1'))
      return -1;
    result=result*2+(*bin-'0');
    if(result<=0) return -1;
  }
  return result;
}


int main ( void )
{
    printf("%d\n",bin2dec("1000000100000101111101"));
    return(0);
}
```

results in -1 because you have this line in it

```
    if(result<=0) return -1;
```

which limits you to size of int - 1 bits. so 15 for a 16 bit int and 31 for a 32 bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

short bin2dec(const char *bin)
{
  short result=0;
  for(;*bin;bin++)
  {
    if((*bin!='0')&&(*bin!='1'))
    {
        printf("here\n");
        return -1;
    }
    result=result*2+(*bin-'0');
    printf("0x%04X\n",result);
    if(result<=0)
    {
        printf("there\n");
        return -1;
    }
  }
  return result;
}


int main ( void )
{
    printf("%d\n",bin2dec("1000000100000101111101"));
    return(0);
}


0x0001
0x0002
0x0004
0x0008
0x0010
0x0020
0x0040
0x0081
0x0102
0x0204
0x0408
0x0810
0x1020
0x2041
0x4082
0xFFFF8105
there
-1
```

remember, plus one/accept gre_gor's answer not mine...